# Not-So-Squishy Slark

Tags: dota

Slark being a squishy hero is a known fact. Standing 1v1 against him is quite hard. Even at low levels. I can't be teaming up all the time just to kill him.

The following are my rather defensive approaches

1. Tower hugging - saves me with very low HP
2. Hex/stun and run
3. Blade mail and assault - potent but he heals and comes back fast.
4. Force staff myself.

Any counter heros or offensive strategies particularly for 1v1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To begin with, early game Slark is essentially about as menacing as a paper napkin. Slark needs a pretty decent baby sitter to survive early game without heavy harassment. After Slark gets to level 6 things get trickier, but the fact remains that *Slark has no survivability when faced with nukes.*

So the effective counter heroes will deal heavy amounts of burst damage and essentially kill Slark before he has time to fully finish his combination of `death pact`, `shadow dance`, and leech enough stat points through `essence shift`.

While you may not always be able to team up to kill a hero, it is still recommended to try to wrangle at least 1 other teammate to assist. But given your criteria, and whether with support or without you will need to provide truesight. So wards, or dust if you intend on going 1 on 1.

---

### Heroes

**Lina** - unloading the early/mid game combination of her `light strike array`, `dragon slave`, and `laguna blade`

**Bane Elemental** - `brain sap`, `fiend's grip`, follow up with another `brain sap` - items to get in the mean time, `necronomicon` so that the minions can pound away while you disable

**Leshrac** - between `diabolic edict` and `pulse nova` Slark will have a pretty hard time standing directly next to you or even using `pounce`. On the off chance you are pounced on `split earth` should be like shooting fish in a barrel to land. And you still have `lightning storm` to cast.

**Nerubian Assassin** - `mana burn`, `impale`, `vendetta`, attack, repeat whichever skill is done it's cooldown.

---

### Items

- observer wards
- sentry wards
- gem of true sight (*situational*)
- necronomicon - (*upgrade this*) minions for added dps and on-demand true sight
- blademail - synergy counter as `essence shift` and damage incoming is redirected
- ghost scepter - disable Slark
- eul's scepter - disable Slark
- force staff - to break pounce link
- blink dagger - to break pounce link

Comment: I must admit, i was actually waiting for your review. +1 for the details. I will try it out soon.

Answer (score 1):

To add on acm's Heroes part.

**BloodSeeker**

Everytime my team picked Slark, there will be a Bloodseeker opposite. Why ?

Bloodseeker have Thirst, and Thirst can reveal Slark or any enemy heroes when they are below 50% HP. This will completely removes the Slark's ability to regenerates when below 50% HP.

Just Rupture slark's ass off.

Comment: Thirst only gives true sight below 25% HP.  I'm not as familiar with Slark's ultimate, but from the description it sounds like the passive works as long as he is invisible.